# Http 503 for some Rest api call

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, http, spring-mvc

I am running an SpringBoot application and I have a controller which defines Rest Api and accepts a request by a list of ids. Normally it works fine but if number of ids gets bigger, then I receive http 503. Interesting thing is that I cannot see any logs that my request was received by controller as well. Therefore I am not able to understand what is happening. Do you have any idea what can be worth to check ?

Answer (score 0):

503 is a error code, which means service or url or controller, that you are requested is not running/available, make sure your jar file is running and also make sure the url you requested is valid. since service is not available you cant see any logs or error messages. because your controller dint receive any request yet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My jar file is running because it handles other request, even same request with less number of element in response body. I am curious if less number of element in request body works, why it does not work otherwise and what blocks my controller to receive request. I was thinking due to number of element it might have some memory issue etc while processing request but having no log confuses me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The 503  error indicate that the server is not ready to handle the request.

There are some limitations for transferring data through URL , basically the length of the URL
In general the limit was 2047 chars and it is different for  different browsers

Comment: Url length should be fine, because if I reduce number of element in request body which is a list, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

503 means Service Unavailable.

I think something is wrong with your request.

You can try to add a custom OncePerRequestFilter and log your HTTP Request.

Comment: As I mention my response body is a list of ids. If I reduce number of element in the list it works.